# Creating a swap chain with an existing render target

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct3d

I have a program that renders to a texture and sends it over USB. I've added a preview window that simply shows the texture as a debugging aid. Normally this window doesn't need to exist so I simply create the window and swap chain when needed and destroy it when done. This means swap chains may come and go, but the render texture always exists.

Is it possible to create a swap chain and have it simply use the existing render texture? Currently I'm doing a `CopyResource` from the render texture to the swap chain back buffer every frame when the preview window exists and I assume that's not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Swapchains come with their surfaces for the presentation, you have to use them.

`CopyResource` or any other solution to blit your original surface texture to the swapchain own are the right thing to do.